# Formatting Negative Numbers with Parentheses

Tags: apex, string, formatting

Formatting numbers on a VF page, but I do a bunch of processing the Apex Class, so I would rather return the formatted String value from the controller.

I am doing something like this, but I just want the second number to appear as "(1500)" rather "-1500" 
Getting lost in the Message Format docs, so hoping someone can guide me in the right direction...

```
List<String> args = new String[]{'0','number','###,###,###'};
system.debug('Positive' + String.format(  ( (1000) - (500.50)  ).round().format(), args) );
system.debug('Negative' + String.format(  ( (-1000) - (500.50)  ).round().format(), args) );
```

Comment: Why can't you format using VF? I don't think it is possible to do what you want with String.format. The args you are passing aren't actually doing any formatting right now. Try changing the second line to `system.debug('Args' + String.format('{0}, {1}, {2}', args) );` and I think you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically it's best to leave the formatting to the visualforce page and leave the controller to handle the model/controller side of things.  You can easily do this in the Visualforce page and if you're using it in a lot of places just put it in a component you can reference all over the place.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###}" rendered="{!value >= 0}">
    <apex:param value="{!value}"/>
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText value="({0, number, ###,###,###})" rendered="{!value < 0}">
    <apex:param value="{!value * -1}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: very nice reply

Comment: Thanks - worked great. The component idea was especially helpful - I think I have been too resistant to their capabilities...

Answer (score 4):

While [Ralph Callaway](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/594/ralph-callaway)'s example is technically correct, it can be simplified.

There is no need for conditional rendering of the `<apex:outputText>` elements, or multiplying the value by `-1`. Instead we can use a subpattern for the negative number format.

From Java docs:

> A [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) pattern contains a positive and negative subpattern, for example, `"#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)"`. Each subpattern has a prefix, numeric part, and suffix. The negative subpattern is optional; if absent, then the positive subpattern prefixed with the localized minus sign (`'-'` in most locales) is used as the negative subpattern. That is, `"0.00"` alone is equivalent to `"0.00;-0.00"`. If there is an explicit negative subpattern, it serves only to specify the negative prefix and suffix; the number of digits, minimal digits, and other characteristics are all the same as the positive pattern. That means that `"#,##0.0#;(#)"` produces precisely the same behavior as `"#,##0.0#;(#,##0.0#)"`.

By using `;` to separate both the positive and negative subpatterns we can use a single `<apex:outputText>` to render both positive and negative values.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, number, ###,###,###;(###,###,###)">
    <apex:param value="{!value}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

When the value is positive, the subpattern `###,###,###` is used and when the value is negative the subpattern `(###,###,###)` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a method in the controller to return the formatted string of a decimal:

```
public string negToParentheses (decimal d){
    if(d<0)
        return '('+string.valueof(-d)+')';
    return string.valueof(d);
}
```